# What exactly is the `$event` 'special variable' in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to beef up my understanding of Vue, and I noticed that [in the docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#accessing-event-argument-in-inline-handlers) on event handling, they say:

"You can pass it into a method using the special `$event` variable, or use an inline arrow function:"

```
<button @click="warn('Form cannot be submitted yet.', $event)">
  Submit
</button>

<!-- using inline arrow function -->
<button @click="(event) => warn('Form cannot be submitted yet.', event)">
  Submit
</button>
```

But they never elaborate on the `$event` var, or what *makes* it special. Does anyone here know?

Comment: Perhaps for not having to write `(event) =>`?

Comment: `click`, `mousemove`, `mouseenter`, `hover`, etc. are all events you can listen to, `$event` is refering to the event of the listener, so `@click` sends the `$event` of that click, you can then access the target with it with `event.target` for example. Same goes for any other listener

Comment: Let's say you want the ID of an element you generated with a loop when you click on it `<div :id=" 'myID' + ID "></div>`, you can either pass the ID `@click="() => { watch("myID" + ID) }"` or get it through the event `const myID = event.target.id`

Comment: It's special because you're pretty sure you didn't define it but it magically exists and refers to `event` arg that is normally passed to event handlers